# How to solve $\ln(y)=\ln(x)e^{\ln(x+1)} $ for x?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

I know that if I have had $y = x^{x+0} $ aka $y = x^x$ I could do

$y = x^x$   //   $x = e^{\ln(x)}$

$y=x^{e^{\ln(x)}}$   // $\ln$()

$\ln(y) = \ln(x)e^{\ln(x)}$ then using Lambert's W function I could directly solve for $x$.

$x=e^{W(\ln(y))}$

What do I do in the case I've stated in the title above where $x^x$ becomes $x^{(x+1)}$ I can't directly use the product log since the $x$ in the exponential function and the $x$ in the log function are not the same, or am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong.  The CAS I have access to (Mathematica 10.3.1) also can't solve your "$x+1$" version for $x$.  There may not be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The tools I have are relatively bad as I'm a student so my best bet was Wolfram Alpha which exceeded in calculation time. This was a part of a slightly more complex problem which I tried to simplify as far as I could and seems to boil down to this. If Mathematica 10 can't solve this then maybe I'm doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you can't simplify $\ln(x+1)$ into $f(\ln(x))$ where  $f$ allows use of Lambert W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow, you can solve for $x$ through [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

$$y=x^{x+1}$$

Invert it...

I now have time to work the problem out.

$$f(x)=x^{x+1}$$

$$f(1)=1,f'(1)\ne0$$

$$f^{-1}(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{w\to1}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{w-1}{w^{w+1}-1}\right)^n$$

This is not reducible as far as I know, so you are stuck with this.

If it doesn't converge for the $x$ value you want to calculate, choose a different $a$ value such that $f'(a)\ne0$.

You also need a background understanding of calculus.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will look into the theorem. I'll update if I manage to solve it before somebody else.

Comment: Again, thank you for editing your post. The original problem was this:

$1-(1-1/q^N)^{M-N-1} > 1/2$ solve for N, do you think that my assumption of this being the "simplified case" was wrong?

Comment: @Ilhan I think $x^{x+1}$ is definitely more simplified.

Comment: @Ilhan I do have to wonder how you managed to simplify it so.

Comment: Haha well in that case I'm stuck and will have to try out all integer values 1 < N < M every time I run into this scenario. I'm a programmer sorry but I probably just amazed you with a inherently stupid assumption of this boiling down to something similar to q^-N^(N-1) = 1/2 asuming M and q are constants.

Thank you again for your patience and effort friend, I've hoped for this to be more simple but I guess I've been proven wrong! @Simple Art

Comment: @Ilhan Yes, simplicity starts to disappear when you run into these weird exponentials and such.

Comment: @Ilhan I would like to mention that Lagrange Inversion Theorem works for almost any function, if you ever need it again.